# Joi how to merge/append/add sub schemas depends on specific inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, schema, joi

I want to make a user input validation in Node.js REST api.

I have this schema for example:

```
let schema = Joi.object().keys({
    client: {
      type: Joi.string().valid(["private", "business"]).required().error(JoiCustomErrors)
    },
 });
```

Now if the user fills the form with **type** as **private**, I want to add **a** to the schema, so it will be looking something like this:

```
let schema = Joi.object().keys({
    client: {
      type: Joi.string().valid(["private", "business"]).required().error(JoiCustomErrors),
      a: Joi.string().required().error(JoiCustomErrors)
    },
  });
```

If the user fills **business** in the *type* field I want to append **b** instead of **a** (some options for the example).

**I have tried:**

```
let b = Joi.string().required().error(JoiCustomErrors);

schema.client.append({b: b}); // 1
schema.client.append(b); // 2
schema.client.b = b; // 3
```

But nothing works I receive an undefined error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined**

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to define both rules for `a` and `b` in the same schema and add conditional requirements on whether they're required or not.

Take a look at the following:

```
Joi.object().keys({
    client: Joi.object().keys({
        type: Joi.string().valid([ 'private', 'business' ]).required(),
        a: Joi.string().when('type', { is: 'private', then: Joi.required() }),
        b: Joi.string().when('type', { is: 'business', then: Joi.required() })
    }).nand('a', 'b')
});
```

This schema makes `client.type` required as you already have it. `a` and `b` have been defined as optional strings but they make use of Joi's [`.when()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhencondition-options) function to create a conditional requirement based on the value of `type`.

If `type` is `'private'`, `a` is required; if it's `'business'`, `b` is required.

I've also added a [`.nand()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectnandpeers) modifier to the `client` object which will forbid `a` and `b` to exist at the same time.

Comment: It seems good solution, just a tiny thing, if I want to access type which is in parent object, how could it be done?

Comment: Unfortunately, as tiny as it seems, Joi doesn't support referencing attributes in parent objects. You can only reference siblings or children. There are methods like [.assert()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectassertref-schema-message) that could be of use but I'm not sure how to apply it in this situation.

Comment: How about working with plain JS schema (with Joi) I mean without use the `Joi.object().keys()`, just use `{}` that way it just as simple as work with a native JS object, you can assign, and access each key in ease. Isn't it?